# Arcade Coffee Table drawer

Tags: furniture, design, drawer

I was wondering if you happen to know what kind of hardware is used on the drawer for this [Coffee Table Arcade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEzC2_s7lqw). Here is a picture of the drawer as it is being pulled out.

[image: Coffee table being opened]

Then fully engaged

[image: Coffee table fully opened]

You will notice that the controls are raised while the drawer is being pulled out.

I do some woodwork, and also design joysticks and MAME installations, and I was interesting in achieving the effect of this drawer, but i'm still in my learning curve and would like some indicators.

This question was originally posted on [Arqade StackExchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/237385/edit)

Comment: Interesting question, and i'd say it's certainly on-topic here. Unfortunately, while I can think of several ways to achieve that effect I don't know how I'd implement it if I had to build one or if there's any off-the-shelf hardware that could be adapted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The retracting control console may be a lot simpler than it looks. For example, you could simply route some diagonal grooves in the sides and insert (stainless steel) dowels into the side edges of the console top, near the rear.  The dowels follow the diagonal grooves in the sides, so when you pull out the console, the controls are raised and when you push it in the controls are lowered.  Here is a rough rendering of what such a design may look like:

[image: abstract design illustration of retracting control console]

Comment: Almost there... I'm orbiting around this idea, only doubt is the "lock" mechanism, when they pull the drawer out on the video, you hear a "click" and it locks into position. 
Maybe routing an S shape would help with the locking at the end of the routed path, but it sounded like when you start jiggling the joysticks on the drawer it could get unlocked with some pressure. 
What do you think ?

Comment: There are drawer slides which lock at full extension; they may have used these. (That's what the click sounded like tome, anyway.) You might want rollers rather than just dowels, for smoother operation.